# No file or variants found for asset: packages/html_editor_enhanced/summernote.html

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

while trying to build apk (flutter build apk --releas), it shows error as follows

*Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
No file or variants found for asset: packages/html_editor_enhanced/summernote.html.
This asset was included from package html_editor_enhanced.
Target aot_android_asset_bundle failed: Exception: Failed to bundle asset files.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'E:\Program Files\Android\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'E:\Program Files\Android\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s
  Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           68.8s
  Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1*

I tried upgrading and downgrading the **html_editor_enhanced:**., but received the same error.

Anyone who can help me solve the issue?

Comment: add your pubspec.yaml

Comment: unable to add file ! pubspec.yaml is too long

Comment: environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"